# magento database restore duplicate entry

Tags: magento

I have some issue when try to restore . I just see  `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1893: Duplicate entry '` this type of error. I don't understand it because I used a blank database and try to restore it. My original backup from `magento 1.6.2` and try to restore in `magento 1.7` . So when try to restore via ubuntu terminal I just see that error. So what is the solution for this type of error. Thanks

Comment: you need to post the full error and what do you mean by restore in magento 1.7?

Comment: have to you tried to disable the foreignkey check?